# I can't get value using rvest

Tags: r, macos, rvest

I'm trying to scrape a set of web pages with rvest package. It works for most of the web pages but I can get a information of rent fee by using rvest

```
url <- "http://www.trademe.co.nz/Browse/CategoryAttributeSearchResults.aspx?search=1&cid=5748&sidebar=1&132=FLAT&selected135=5&134=1&135=5&216=0&216=0&217=0&217=0&153=&122=0&122=0&123=0&123=0&59=25000&59=35000&178=0&178=0&sidebarSearch_keypresses=0&sidebarSearch_suggested=0"
rent_html <- read_html(url)

html_nodes(rent_html, "div.property-card-subtitle") # it works
html_nodes(rent_html, "div.list-view-card-price") # but this is not works
```

I want to get value of rent price on the web but I don't know how to access to it.

Comment: `html_nodes(rent_html, "div.property-card-price-container")`?

Comment: I just want to get information about [div.list-view-card-price] inner [div.property-card-price-containe]. Is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
rent_prices <- rent_html %>% html_nodes("div.property-card-price") %>% html_text()
#> rent_prices
# [1] "$270 per week" "$250 per week" "$350 per week" "$300 per week"  $350 per week" "$290 per week"
# [7] "$350 per week" "$250 per week" "$330 per week" "$350 per week" "$330 per week" "$265 per week"
#[13] "$300 per week" "$300 per week" "$340 per week" "$350 per week" "$250 per week" "$325 per week"
#[19] "$320 per week" "$310 per week" "$300 per week" "$350 per week" "$270 per week" "$320 per week"
#[25] "$350 per week" "$295 per week" "$260 per week" "$305 per week" "$285 per week" "$320 per week"
#[31] "$340 per week" "$350 per week" "$300 per week" "$290 per week" "$330 per week" "$285 per week"
#[37] "$290 per week" "$270 per week"
```

Comment: Wow! It works!! how do you find *property-card-price*? I can't find it on the html code.

Comment: Could you explain it more detail? I also using firefox inspector option but I can't still find **property-card-price**. the price is set around of **div.list-view-card-price** as I said above.

Comment: You are probably in the "List View" mode of that page. Switch to the "Gallery View" mode by clicking on the icon with four squares on the upper right of the page. Then it shouldn't be difficult to find.

Comment: I found it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The URL you quoted doesn't contain the list values; you've clicked on the list option to get there. Add `&v=List` to the URL and then

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://www.trademe.co.nz/Browse/CategoryAttributeSearchResults.aspx?search=1&cid=5748&sidebar=1&132=FLAT&selected135=5&134=1&135=5&216=0&216=0&217=0&217=0&153=&122=0&122=0&123=0&123=0&59=25000&59=35000&178=0&178=0&sidebarSearch_keypresses=0&sidebarSearch_suggested=0&v=List"
rent_html <- read_html(url)
html_nodes(rent_html, "div.list-view-card-price")
```

works.

Comment: Thanks Joathan, but it's result is not perfect that represent price with date together. Is there no way to access to only price value without date? or should I pull the information of it again?

Comment: If you want to do additional processing on it then you can do that. `html_nodes` extracts the entire element.